# Google fit - Putting app to sleep & optimizing battery usage: Do they interrupt tracking KM distance?

Tags: samsung, battery, google-fit

I'm using google fit to track my walking distance for pokemon go, and I'm not sure if I need to make it "never sleep" or not allow it to be optimized for it to work well in the background.

Does sleeping apps save that much battery? Should I allow google fit to never sleep or optimized for battery for it to work well? Is it worth putting it to never sleep if it doesn't take up that much battery?

Comment: Optimizing apps does save battery. How much? Depends on the app. No general answer. If you need the app to work always, don't optimize, it's that simple.

Comment: Thank you, I worry too much about optimizing battery and app usage so I wanted to know if anyone knew specifically whether or not some settings won't affect their usability in my context and save battery at the same time. I don't think it's a huge battery drain so I'll keep it unoptimized.

Comment: If you are serious about battery, rooting the device goes a long way